# Controlled concurrency with amazon SQS

Tags: amazon-sqs

I have a multiple publishers publishing events for a shipment entity on an SQS queue and I have multiple listeners on it for parallel processing. But I want events for a particular shipment (having some identifier) to be processed sequentially in order. Is there any in-built feature to support this?

ActiveMQ has a similar concept of [Exclusive Consumer](http://activemq.apache.org/exclusive-consumer.html) which is not exactly what I need but could be adapted

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is; they are called [FIFO (*F*irst-*I*n-*F*irst-*O*ut) queues](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/FIFO-queues.html)

> FIFO (First-In-First-Out) **queues are designed to enhance messaging between applications when the order of operations and events is critical**, or where duplicates can't be tolerated.

You will need to ensure that the messages you want processed in the correct order belong to the same Message Group ID:-

> The tag that specifies that a message belongs to a specific message group. **Messages that belong to the same message group are always processed one by one, in a strict order relative to the message group** (however, messages that belong to different message groups might be processed out of order).

Hope that helps!

Comment: I think this works only when you've single consumer. SQS will ensure ordering of messages with a single group id when delivering it to that consumer. But with multiple consumers, does SQS ensure some kind of listener affinity like messages with same group id are delivered to only one consumer?